# Left Join returns duplicate (two) rows with different attribute values (one column contains joined value, other contains null)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have two tables:

**Person Table:**

```
 ---------------------
|Person_ID | Phone_ID |
|---------------------|
|1234      | 12       |
|345       | 10       |
|43        | 33       |
|55        | 27       |
-----------------------
```

**Phone Table:**

```
 --------------------------
|Phone_ID  |  Phone_Number |
|--------------------------|
|  12      |  null         |
|  10      |  9876         |
|  33      |  9654         |
|  27      |  null         |
 --------------------------
```

When I execute the query:

```
select t1.person_id, t2.phone_id 
from person t1
left join
phone t2
on t1.phone_id=t2.phone_id;
```

I get results:

```
 --------------------------
| Person_ID | Phone_number |
|--------------------------|
| 1234      | null         |
| 345       | 9876         |
| 345       | null         |
| 43        | 9654         |
| 43        | null         |
| 55        | null         |
 --------------------------
```

How do I eliminate the problem of getting `null` values for the person id which already has phone number?

Comment: It's not possible to get this result with your data & Select.

Comment: As dnoeth said, your select can't return that result from the specified table data.

Comment: As per your sample data, result should contain only 4 rows. However in your output there are two rows for ID 345 and 43.

Comment: your query do not return that results. are you sure ?

Comment: Person `345`'s phone number is both 9876 and null...? And the key for this table is...? If a phone number is unique by definition, it needs an id because...? Methinks you need to fix your data before you can get anything sensible out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your query do not return that results.
```

most probably your **phone** and **person** tables are not like you expected.

You should truncate these tables and reinsert data . Then reexecute your query.

```
 truncate table  Person ; 

truncate table  Phone ; 

 insert into person
 select 1234 ,12 from dual union all
 select 345, 10  from dual union all
 select 43  ,   33   from dual union all
 select 55 ,  27  from dual ;

 commit;

  insert into phone
 select 12 ,  null from dual union all
 select 10 ,  9876 from dual union all
 select  33  ,  9654 from dual union all
 select  27  ,null from dual ;


 commit;

 select t1.person_id, t2.phone_id 
    from person t1
    left join  phone t2
    on t1.phone_id=t2.phone_id;
```

Comment: why no ? if you insert these rows and then your query get 4 rows

Comment: data can be null , but the result is correct which we expected

Answer (score 0):

Your query is working well, as i have checked with dynamically creating table, try this, run this directly in your  query window:

```
DECLARE @persons TABLE (
person_id INT,
phone_id INT )

DECLARE @phones TABLE (
phone_id INT,
phonenumber BIGINT )


INSERT INTO @persons VALUES(1234,12),(345,10),(43,33),(55,27)
INSERT INTO @phones VALUES(12,null),(10,9876),(33,9654),(27,null)

SELECT * FROM @persons 
SELECT * FROM @phones 

select t1.person_id, t2.phone_id 
from @persons t1
left join
@phones t2
on t1.phone_id=t2.phone_id;
```

AND if you need to eliminate `null` containing entries, you can just use condition in the last:

```
WHERE 'column_name' IS NOT NULL
```

OR if you want to replace null with blank or some value, you can just use the:

```
ISNULL(column_name,'replacement_value') AS new_col_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH actual_phones AS
     ( SELECT phone_id, phone_number
         FROM phone
        WHERE phone_number IS NOT NULL )
SELECT person_id, phone_number 
  FROM person NATURAL JOIN actual_phones
UNION
SELECT person_id, null AS phone_number 
  FROM person
 WHERE phone_id NOT IN ( SELECT phone_id
                            FROM actual_phones );
```